# Generation of infinite list of Ints with MWC-random

Tags: haskell, random

I would like to write a function like this:

```
myFnc :: Gen -> ([Int], Gen)
```

using [MWC Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.12.0.1/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#v:initialize). General idea is to create first `Gen` using predefined seed, then generate infinite sequences of `Int`s and new `Gen`s in absolutely pure manner.

So I started trying to get `Gen` from seed represented as `Int`. Documentation says I can do it with [`initialize`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.12.0.1/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#v:initialize) function. Very well, let's see, it takes vector of `Word32`s, so tried this to get at least one random `Int`:

```
import System.Random.MWC
import Data.Vector.Generic

rere :: IO ()
rere =
    do gen <- initialize (singleton 42)
       x   <- uniform gen :: Int
       print x
```

but it does not compile. Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘m0 a0’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- uniform gen :: Int
    In the expression:
      do { gen <- initialize (singleton 42);
           x <- uniform gen :: Int;
           print x }
```

I looked at documentation, but it seems infinitely far from my very very simple initial desire...

It seems like I cannot use [`uniform`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.12.0.1/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#v:uniform) too, because it returns value inside monad, so I don't really know how to make a simple plain list of `Int`s from all these stuff.

---

For example, here is what I want to implement, but with `System.Random`:

```
import System.Random

mkStdGen 5 -- first: that's how to create generator from given Int

myFnc :: StdGen -> ([Int], StdGen) -- second: desired function
myFnc g = (randoms g, fst . split $ g)
```

This works.

Comment: "but it does not compile" What is the error?

Comment: The compiler is pointing you in the right direction. You are trying to unify an `Int` with `m0 a0`. In this case, the assignment is inside of the IO monad, so try changing the type annotation to `x   <- uniform gen :: IO Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [implemented a sample of this on FP Haskell Center](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/chad/snippets/random-code-snippets/generation-of-infinite-list-of-ints-with-mwc-random). The core of the implementation is:

```
randoms :: (Variate a, PrimMonad m) => Gen (PrimState m) -> m [a]
randoms gen =
    loop
  where
    loop = return $ unsafeInlinePrim $ do
        x <- uniform gen
        xs <- loop
        return $! x : xs
```

Note that this has a different type signature than what you asked for. In particular, there's no concept of "split" in mwc-random. Also, getting random numbers in mwc-random is inherently a mutable action, so we need to live in some `PrimMonad` as well as use unsafe inlining. This is probably safe presuming you never use the `Gen` provided somewhere else.

However, I think you should try to restructure your program to accept the mutable nature of mwc-random, or switch to a pure random number generator like [mersenne-random-pure64](https://www.stackage.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64).

Comment: Hmm, mersenne-random-pure64 looks interesting... I'll give it a try.  Maybe I've chosen a wrong library for what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Unfortunately the link to the FP Haskell Center doesn't work. Could you update it?

Answer (score 1):

In System.Random.MWC, "uniform" returns a type "m a" but you are trying to constrain it to Int. That is what your error is complaining about.

Put

```
x :: Int
```

on the previous line.